# JavaScript incremental game interval looping

Tags: javascript, loops, intervals

I am making a very simple incremental game but I can't figure out a good way to implement upgrades.

I want to make a button which makes the cursor loop go faster. Basically, you get 1 coins for every cursor every second. And the upgrade should make it so it will take less millieseconds for every loop.

I'm trying to do this with `window.setInterval` but I can't figure out how to make it variable, my method does not work.

```js
var coins = 0;

function coinClick(number){
 coins = coins + number;
 document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = coins;
}

var cursors = 0;
var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
var cursorUpgrades = 0;
var cursorUpgradeCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,cursorUpgrades));

function buyCursor(){
 var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
 if(coins >= cursorCost){
  cursors = cursors + 1;
  coins = coins - cursorCost;
  document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
  document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
 };
 var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
 document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};

function buyCursorUpgrade(){
 if(coins >= cursorUpgradeCost){
  cursorUpgrades = cursorUpgrades + 1;
  coins = coins - cursorUpgradeCost;
  document.getElementById('cursorUpgrades').innerHTML = cursorUpgrades;
  document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
 };
 var nextUpgradeCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,cursorUpgrades));
 document.getElementById('cursorUpgradeCost').innerHTML = nextUpgradeCost;
};

window.setInterval(function(){
 coinClick(cursors);
}, Math.round(1000 - 100 * cursorUpgrades));

function save(){
 localStorage.setItem("coins",JSON.stringify(coins));
 localStorage.setItem("cursors",JSON.stringify(cursors));
 localStorage.setItem("cursorCost",JSON.stringify(cursorCost));
 console.log('Saved.');
};

function load(){
 console.log('Loaded.');
 coins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coins'));
 cursors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cursors'));
 cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
 document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
 document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
 document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = cursorCost;
};

function resetgame(){
 coins = 0;
 cursors = 0;
 cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
 document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
 document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
 document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = cursorCost;
};

var savegamecoins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("coins"));
var savegamecursors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cursors"));

if (coins == 0 && cursors == 0) {
  coins = savegamecoins;
  cursors = savegamecursors;
  cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
  document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
  document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
  document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = cursorCost;
};
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onClick="coinClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
  <br />
  Coins: <span id="coins">0</span>
  <br />
  <button onClick="buyCursor()">Buy cursor</button>
  <br />
  Cursors: <span id="cursors">0</span>
  <br />
  Cursor Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span>
  <br />
  <button onClick="buyCursorUpgrade()">Buy Cursor Upgrade</button>
  <br />
  Cursor Upgrades: <span id="cursorUpgrades">0</span>
  <br />
  Cursor Upgrade Cost: <span id="cursorUpgradeCost">100</span>
  <br />
  <button onClick="save()">Save Game</button>
  <br />
  <button onClick="load()">Load Game</button>
  <br />
  <button onClick="resetgame()">Reset Game</button>
  <br />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean speed up the loop if you upgrade cursor?

Comment: I don't know if I understand well... But if what you want to achieve is to make the timer of  `setInterval` variable, you can consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963377/use-variable-as-time-in-setinterval-settimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of errors in your `js` code.

- You never change the value of `coins`: `coins + number` (at the beginning when calling `coinClick(cursors)` `coins =0` and `number=0` which explains why the coins you are displaying does not change.
- If you want the timer of your `setInterval` to be variable, you can consider using `setTimeout` instead as it is was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963377/use-variable-as-time-in-setinterval-settimeout).

Below are some changes I made in your `js` code

```js
var coins = 0;

function coinClick(number){
    //I made a change here so as the variable "coins" could vary
    coins = coins + 1;
    document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = coins;
}

var cursors = 0;
var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
var cursorUpgrades = 0;
var cursorUpgradeCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,cursorUpgrades));

function buyCursor(){
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    if(coins >= cursorCost){
        cursors = cursors + 1;
        coins = coins - cursorCost;
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
        document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};

function buyCursorUpgrade(){
    if(coins >= cursorUpgradeCost){
        cursorUpgrades = cursorUpgrades + 1;
        coins = coins - cursorUpgradeCost;
        document.getElementById('cursorUpgrades').innerHTML = cursorUpgrades;
        document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
    };
    var nextUpgradeCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,cursorUpgrades));
    document.getElementById('cursorUpgradeCost').innerHTML = nextUpgradeCost;
};
/*
setInterval(function(){
    coinClick(cursors);
    console.log("execution")
}, Math.round(1000 - 100 * cursorUpgrades));*/

function periodicall() {
    coinClick(cursors);
    //if you change cursorUpgrades, your timer will change
    timer = Math.round(1000 - 100 * cursorUpgrades)
    console.log(timer);
    setTimeout(periodicall, timer);
};
periodicall();

function save(){
    localStorage.setItem("coins",JSON.stringify(coins));
    localStorage.setItem("cursors",JSON.stringify(cursors));
    localStorage.setItem("cursorCost",JSON.stringify(cursorCost));
    console.log('Saved.');
};

function load(){
    console.log('Loaded.');
    coins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coins'));
    cursors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cursors'));
    cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
    document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = cursorCost;
};

function resetgame(){
    coins = 0;
    cursors = 0;
    cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
    document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = cursorCost;
};

var savegamecoins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("coins"));
var savegamecursors = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cursors"));

if (coins == 0 && cursors == 0) {
    coins = savegamecoins;
    cursors = savegamecursors;
    cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));
    document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
    document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = cursorCost;
};
```